# Como hacer un enlace para mostrar más información con PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html5

quisiera saber qué es lo que necesito o como puedo hacer para mostrar la información de un producto.

Tengo este código de PHP para mostrar la información de los productos de la base de datos.

```
        $sqlQuery .= " ORDER By precio";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
        $totalResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $searchResultHTML = '';
        if($totalResult > 0) {
            /*while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {*/
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $searchResultHTML .= '
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card-box-a card-shadow">
                        <div class="img-box-a">
                            <img src="img/'. $row['imagen'] .'" alt="Propiedades en Costa Rica" class="img-a img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-overlay">
                            <div class="card-overlay-a-content">
                                <div class="card-header-a">
                                    <h2 class="card-title-a">
                                        <a href="#">'. $row['nombre'] .'</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body-a">
                                    <div class="price-box d-flex">
                                        <span class="price-a">Precio | $ '. $row['precio'] .'</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="property-single.html" class="link-a">Click here to view
                                    <span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer-a">
                                    <ul class="card-info d-flex justify-content-around">
                                        <li>
                                            <h4 class="card-info-title">Provincia</h4>
                                            <span class="centrar-span">'. $row['provincia'] .'</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <h4 class="card-info-title">Cuartos</h4>
                                            <span class="centrar-span">'. $row['cuartos'] .'</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <h4 class="card-info-title">Garajes</h4>
                                            <span>'. $row['garaje'] .'</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <h4 class="card-info-title">Baños</h4>
                                            <span>'. $row['banos'] .'</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            }
        } else {
            $searchResultHTML = '<h3>No se ha encontrado ningún producto..</h3>';
        }
        return $searchResultHTML;
```

Y el resultado es este,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo quisiera que al darle click en "Click here to view" en un producto X abra una pantalla con la información de ese producto.

Comment: en una url en un modal? como? te funciona un javascript fetch

Comment: Correcto en una URL, lo que he hecho es tomar el id de la propiedad y pasarlo a la URL para luego validarlo. Pero no se como hacer eso

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
 <a href="property-single.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" class="link-a">Click here to view
   <span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span>
  </a>
```

ahora en php hacemos:

```
<?php
// validamos si esta definido el id en la url
if(!isset($_GET["id"]) ){
      // terminamos la ejecucion
      die("este producto no existe");
}
// filtramos la variable para no tener sql injection
$id = filter_var ( $_GET["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// resto del codigo
?>
```